# How do I print list = ['a','b','c'], using a custom font with tkinter for python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to print out a list using tkinter and a custom font with the font family that is named Voynich.  I have made several lists named Vglyphs that use the random module and I would like to display the output in the voynich text font.  If you loaded this piece of code into your python idle as you can see it prints the text.  I would really like to see the Vglyphs = list print the output of the Voynich font yet I'm new to python and I'm slugging through this as it is. Thanks for any help :)

```
 import random
 from tkinter import *
 from tkinter.font import Font

 root = Tk()

 my_font = Font(family="Voynich", size=16)
 label = Label(root, text="I would like this t to print, that is set to Vglyphs", 
 font=my_font).pack()
 root.geometry("300x300+120+120")
 root.mainloop()





 while True:
     e = int(input("Enter a number 1 through 12 to make a Voynich Vord: "))
Vglyphs1 = ['y','e','9']
Vglyphs2 = ['o','a','8','1','3']
Vglyphs3 = ['1','8','3','4']
Vglyphs4 = ['o','c','a','8']







if e == 3 :

    
        
    t  = random.choices(Vglyphs3,weights=[6,8,2,2])
    
        
    print(*t , end="" )
    
    pass
if e == 3:
    t = random.choices(Vglyphs4,weights=[13,10,8,8])
    
    
        
    print(*t   , end="" )
    root.mainloop()
    pass
if e == 3:
    t = random.choices(Vglyphs1,weights=[3,4,11])
    
        
    print(*t   , end="" )
    print("\n")
    continue
        
if e == 2: 
    t = random.choices(Vglyphs2,weights=[13,8,8,6,2],)
    
    
    print(*t , end="" )
    pass
    
    
if e == 2:
    t = random.choices(Vglyphs1,weights=[7,6,4])
    
    
    print(*t  , end="")
    print("\n")
    continue
elif e < 3:
    
    print(*t  , end="")
    break
```

Comment: Possible useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158220/tkinter-understanding-mainloop

Comment: tkinter supports only built in fonts, for additional fonts, you might need `pylget` library.

Comment: Hi, Cool Cloud can you show me a solution in pylget as I do have that module loaded.  I would like to print the list for Vglyphs1, Vglyphs2, Vglyphs3 and Vglyphs4.